# cosine distance over a list of values using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance, trigonometry

My goal is to compute cosine similarity for each value in the f-list (`f=[[3492.6], [13756.2], [22442.1], [22361.9], [26896.4]]`)  by taking a value from the list and compute how close in terms of cosine distance the rest values in the list are from it. Hence the result should be five different similarity scores. However, for some reason, I keep getting 1.0 as the cosine similarity even when I tested the code on other data sets. Obviously, `[22361.9]` is more similar to `[22442.1]` than `[13756.2]` (with respect to distance). See code below;

```
import numpy.linalg as LA
import numpy as np
import sys

f=[[3492.6], [13756.2], [22442.1], [22361.9], [26896.4]]
cx = lambda a, b : round(np.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 2)
for c in f:
     for i in f:
        cosine=cx(c, i)
        print cosine
```

Any ideas? many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the dataset? Use [this](http://www.appliedsoftwaredesign.com/archives/cosine-similarity-calculator) and check results.

Comment: @SukritKalra, thanks for the response. The cosine calculated you linked me to works fine, but takes only two vectors at a time. I have over a hundred tf-idf weight vectors compute simultaneously. Hence I created a for loop which doesn't seem to be working accurately.

Comment: That's what the response was for. I checked a couple of values on your dataset and the all evaluated to 1. I didn't find any problem with your code, so I didn't post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to use the wrong similarity metric. Cosine similarity measures the similarity in orientation of two vectors. If they have the same orientation, as in your case, as they are all one dimensional, the result will always be 1. If you try to apply the formula to one-dimensional vectors, you can easily check this.

Comment: thanks for the response. Each value in the f-list represents a tf-idf weight vector for a document; in order words, the f-list contains 5 documents. My understanding is that, you can compute cosine similarity between two documents from their tf-idf weight (information retrieval), which I have already calculate (the f-list).

Comment: As far as I have understood, you are right. The problem here is that you are trying to compute the similarity of documents for which you are considering only one term, and this will not work with cosine similarity

Comment: Hi @markusian...its not one term, each value in the f-list is a multi-dimensional vector(where each term in a document is a vector, and the sum of the vectors (terms) in a document is just one value in the f-list).

Comment: @Tiger1, I see. If you want to use the cosine similarity as a metric, each of the element of the f-list should be a vector itself, and not the sum of its elements.

Comment: @makusian, I actually thought cosine distance metric could be used with tf-idf, and that the tf-idf vectors in a document are usually added up to form a weight vector that cosine similarity metric works with.

Comment: @Tiger1, cosine similarity can be used with tf-idf, but in this case you have to use the complete feature vector for each document. I suggest to check this [link](http://www.ir-facility.org/scoring-and-ranking-techniques-tf-idf-term-weighting-and-cosine-similarity) for better understanding.

Comment: @makusian, thanks a lot. Its now clear to me. I shouldn't have summed up the individual tf-idf vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Your "vectors" are all scalars, so they all have a cosine similarity of 1.0.  You can think of a scalar as a vector along the only axis in a one-dimensional space and the cosine similarity is based upon the angle between two vectors.  In a one-dimensional space the angles between the "vectors" are always 0, so all "vectors" are extremely similar in terms of this comparison.

Use multi-dimensional vectors instead:

```
f = [ [3492.6, 2134.1],
      [13756.2, 243234.3],
      [22442.1, 23424.0],
      [22361.9, 23482.4],
      [26896.4, 126875.4] ]
```

Output:

```
1.0
0.57
0.97
0.97
0.69
0.57
1.0
0.76
0.76
0.99
0.97
0.76
1.0
1.0
0.85
0.97
0.76
1.0
...
```

The remaining 1.0 values in this list are from where you compare a vector with itself, so you might want to skip these (as they always will result in 1.0).

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I like your idea of multidimensional vectors. The fact is, each value in the f-list is multidimensional vector (I added up the vectors for each unique term in a document to form a weight vector(multidimensional)). Hence the f-list comprises of 5 multidimensional vectors.